# Splitting string for expressions array

Tags: java, regex

I was trying to split a string into an array of numbers and operators, for example getting `["2.1" , "+" , "(", "sin" , "2" , ")"]` from `"2.1+(sin 2)"`.

How to solve this correctly? I tried to use `java.util.regex.Pattern`, but I don't know how to extract all suitable elements.

Comment: Please post your code, and try to explain what other alternatives you're looking for, and why. Your question, for now, doesn't meet the Stack Overflow standards.

Comment: you can use the `split()` method to achieve this task

Comment: You would need a parser program to do that; also, what do you want to do with the tokens you have extracted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do matching or splitting. Here comes the one through splitting.

```
String s = "2.1+(sin 2)";
String parts[] = s.split("\\s+|(?=[^.\\w\\s])|(?<=[^.\\w\\s])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Through matching using Pattern and Matcher classes.

```
String s = "2.1+(sin 2)";
ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>(); 
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?|[a-zA-Z]+|[^\\s\\w\\.]").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
    lst.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(lst);
```

Output:

```
[2.1, +, (, sin, 2, )]
```